# Website design sliced...but with issues

Tags: html, css, photoshop

I have a web template im working on, it was given to me as a psd but im a little confused. The width of the page is 1024 so when I export it and load it into html it has white space on the sides. Is there an easy way of dealing with so that the graphic spans the browser...?

Comment: add <style type="text/css"> html,body {margin:0px} </style> to your header?

Comment: Why an image size is just a few pixels too wide to fit in a maximised browser using a standard (although less common these days) screen size if 1024x768? (It is too wide because window borders and scrollbars require space)

Answer (score 0):

Easy? That is somewhat subjective.

To span the width of the browser window, a design needs to either stretch (not a good idea as this introduces distortion and pixilation), tile (either in its entirety or just in part), or blend to a solid background (or another tiled image).

There isn't a quick fix.